# How to fetch version from search results using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am executing [NativeSearchQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/NativeSearchQuery.html) in Springframework to execute search operation. I am trying to fetch "_version" value from response through Java API. The following is the sample request and response related to this use case

```
GET /my-index/_doc/foo-bar

{
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "foo-bar",
  "_version" : 88,
  "_seq_no" : 169,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "_class" : "fooBar",
    "value" : 1250087,
    "creatdDateTime" : "20210203T124928.913Z",
    "ModifiedDateTime" : "20210203T124928.913Z"
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch _version=88 from above response through JAVA API using NativeSearchQuery. How to get this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Spring Data Elasticsearch, you need to have a property of type `Long` annotated with `@Version`. Spring Data Elasticsearch will then populate this property with the version value.

Answer (score 0):

At the request level, you don't need to do anything as the `_version` field is [always returned](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/63eebdea882f89ce3219b5c407bf9bda393a3bfd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/RequestFactory.java#L1077) from search queries.

Each search hit present in the response will be [transformed to a Document instance](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/63eebdea882f89ce3219b5c407bf9bda393a3bfd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/document/DocumentAdapters.java#L184-L186) and if the `_version` value is >= 0, then the version value will be set on the Document instance.

Then the `NativeSearchQuery.search()` method will return an instance of `SearchHits` which contains and array of `SearchHit` and that class provides a [`getVersion()` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/63eebdea882f89ce3219b5c407bf9bda393a3bfd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java#L309-L315)